# Changing outer templates in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm converting a product management admin site to use Angular - I have all my views (product list, detail view, edit, etc) showing inside an ng-view on my admin page. All good there. However I have a link for each product that lets me print it's info - it currently uses a different outer template as the others.

What would be the angular way of handling this?

App:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    // all routes but print use an index.html template
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/order/manage.html',
        controller: ManageOrderCtrl
      }).
      when('/order/:id', {
       templateUrl: '/partials/order/_view.html',
        controller: ViewOrderCtrl
      }).
      when('/order/edit/:id', {
       templateUrl: '/partials/order/_edit.html',
        controller: ViewOrderCtrl
      }).
      // I want this link to not use the same outer template (i.e. something like printer.html as well as use custom headers)
      when('/order/print/:id', {
       templateUrl: '/partials/order/_print.html',
        controller: PrintOrderCtrl
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

In my manage list:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
  <a title="Print product sheet" href="/order/print/{{ order._id }}"></a>
</div>
```

Right now this would cause _print.html to be placed inside the same ng-view as the other. I do want it to open in a new window - would I just make a new App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a service and inside that service do a ajax call to fetch the html. Now your html will contains placeholders i.e. {{}}, so you need to a template library(e.g. mustache) to substitute those {{}} with the real data

```
factory('print', ["$window", function($window) {
/* service in charge of printing */
return function(templateUrl, context) {
    /* send a GET request to templateUrl for template, render the template with context
     * and open the content in a new window.
     */
    $.ajax({
        url: templateUrl,
        async: false,   //otherwise the popup will be blocked
        success: function(html) {
            var template = html.replace('<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n', '').replace("</html>", ''),
                output = Mustache.render(template, context);
            $window.open().document.documentElement.innerHTML = output;
        }
    });
};
```

}]);